# Probability to draw at least k red balls, but from multiple bags

Tags: probability

Imagine to have $x$ bags.

Each bag contains a known number of balls. Each bag may have a number of balls which is different from the other bags.

In each bag, there are a known number of red balls. The number of red balls may be different from bag to bag.

Now you are told to draw exactly $j$ balls from each bag. The balls are not replaced.

At the end, you will have drawn $x\!\cdot\!j$ balls.

What's the probability that in those $x\!\cdot\!j$ balls, at least $k$ are red?

I know how to calculate the probability to draw at least $k$ red balls from a single bag, but how to combine that with multiple bags?

Comment: Please follow the guidelines outlined by [How to ask a good question?](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) and [How to ask a homework question?](https://goo.gl/Fyfb22).

Comment: Thanks @GNUSupporter, I am trying to improve my question.

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm sorry to ask an off-topic question.  How does solving this problem help understanding the general [tag:probability-theory]?

Comment: @GNUSupporter I am just humbling trying to get some help with a problem I have, that's it. I am trying to find a solution myself. I will be happy to publish it if I find it. Anyway, I think this problem may lead to an interesting discussion, since I haven't found a similar question in the archive.

Comment: I see.  Let's wait for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing something about how many balls of each color are in each bag there is no way to answer the question.  There could be all white balls and the probability is $0$.  There could be all red balls and (assuming $k \le xj$) the probability is $1$.  What you would have to do is consider all the ways you could distribute the $k$ red balls among the bags, compute the probability of each, and add them up.  For example, if there are two bags and $k=4$ you can get four red balls out of the first bag and none out of the second, or three plus one, or so on.  There are five possibilities and if you know the composition of the bags you can compute each probability.